# How to download a driver on Windows, install on Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers

This is kind of an odd question and I'm not sure how to word it well, but I'll try to give as much detail as possible.

So recently I've gotten interested in Linux and installed Ubuntu on my PC alongside  Windows 10. It's great and all but there's one problem — I don't have internet access. I use a wifi adapter and I'm guessing I'm missing drivers or something. I've found a possible solution [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/ubuntu-18-04-driver-for-usb-wifi-ac-12000-dual-band-4175628850/) as it seems he was in the same situation I was, the problem is I don't have an ethernet cable or anything, so there's no way for me to download this. But I do have internet on Win10! So my question is, how do I download the drivers on Windows and transfer it to Linux? Can I just download it on to any drive on windows then open it up on linux?

Comment: First off, identify your computer name off the internet on your Windows 10. Then we'll look for compatible drivers for it

Comment: If it's just a .deb package - it seems to be - just download it like any other file, to a media that you can then connect and use in Ubuntu -or, in a dual-boot, save it in a location accessible (readable) by Ubuntu -, double-click, Ubuntu Software opens, click "install", reboot, done!

Answer (score 0):

The quickest/safest way to do it is to download the driver file in Windows. Then copy the driver file to a flash drive. Boot into Ubuntu. Copy the file from the flash drive to the Ubuntu desktop. Double-click on the driver file icon to begin the installation.

If you don't have a flash drive, download the driver file in Windows. Place the file into your Documents folder. Boot into Ubuntu. Start `Files` (Navigator) and mount the Windows C: drive by clicking its name in the left pane. Be careful here... do not make any changes on the C: drive, and don't leave it mounted for more time than it takes to copy the file to your Ubuntu desktop. Then unmount the Windows C: drive by clicking the **eject** icon next to its name in the `Files` window. Then proceed with the driver install.

In the future, it would be better to create a separate NTFS disk partition that can be shared between Windows and Ubuntu (both Windows and Ubuntu can read/write to NTFS partitions).

**WARNING**! Do **NOT** install a Windows driver that says it'll read/write to ext4 partitions! It **WILL** corrupt your Ubuntu installation.